# Delete a user from a role in jasper server using Rest

Tags: roles, jasperserver

How to delete a user from a role or disable the user from that particular role in JasperReports Server? But I need the role in the main tenant. It should only be removed from the role (Group)

What I am doing now is a goof up like:

Method: DELETE

URL: `http://localhost:8080/reportservice/rest/user/username|TenantID`

Payload:

```
<user>
    <tenantId>tenantID</tenantId>
    <username>{username}</username>
    <emailAddress>{emailAddress}</emailAddress>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <externallyDefined>true</externallyDefined>
    <fullName>{fullName}</fullName>
    <roles>
        <externallyDefined>false</externallyDefined>
        <roleName>ROLE_USER</roleName>
    </roles>
</user>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the REST API Reference Manual (6.3.0):

To modify the properties of a user account, put all desired information in a user descriptor, and include it in a
PUT request to the users service, with the existing user ID (username) specified in the URL.

- In the community edition of the server, or commercial editions without organizations, use the first form of
  the URL.
- In commercial editions with organizations, use the second URL to specify the user’s organization. When
  specifying the organization, use its unique ID, not its path. When logged in as the system admin
  (superuser), use the first URL to modify users of the root organization.

To modify a user, the user ID in the URL must already exist on the server or in the organization. If the user ID
doesn’t exist, a user account will be created, as described in 21.3, “Creating a User,” on page 155.

Method: PUT

URL:

1. http://:/jasperserver[-pro]/rest_v2/users/userID
2. http://:/jasperserver[-pro]/rest_v2/organizations/orgID/users/userID

Content-Type:

application/xml

application/json

Content:

A user descriptor that includes the properties you want to change. Do not
specify the following properties:

- username – Specified in the URL and cannot be modified in the descriptor.
- tenantID – Specified in the URL and cannot be modified in the descriptor.
- externallyDefined – Computed automatically by the server.
- previousPasswordChangeTime – Computed automatically by the server.

Return Value on Success:

200 OK – The user properties were successfully
updated.

Typical Return Values on Failure:

404 Not Found – When the organization ID cannot be
resolved.

To add a role to the user, specify the entire list of roles with the desired role added. **To remove a role from a
user, specify the entire list of roles with the desired role removed.** The following example shows the descriptor
in JSON format:

```
{
"enabled":true,
"password":"newPassword",
"roles":[
{"name":"ROLE_USER"},
{"name":"ROLE_STOREMANAGER", "tenantId":"organization_1"}]
}
```